# What does the error mean? about C++ template argument

Tags: c++, templates

```
#include <stdio.h>

template<typename T, typename T2, template <typename T> class TemplateClass>

class TemplateTemplateClass {
public:
    TemplateTemplateClass(const TemplateClass& tempClass)
        : _internalClass(tempClass) {
    }

    void doTest() {
        _internalClass.doTest();
    }
private:
    TemplateClass _internalClass;
};
```

Above code when compiling will give error message below:

```
$ g++ TemplateTemplateClass.cpp
TemplateTemplateClass.cpp:7:33: error: invalid use of template-name 'TemplateClass' without an argument list
TemplateTemplateClass.cpp:7:48: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of 'tempClass' with no type [-fpermissive]
TemplateTemplateClass.cpp:15:5: error: invalid use of template-name 'TemplateClass' without an argument list
TemplateTemplateClass.cpp: In constructor 'TemplateTemplateClass<T, T2, TemplateClass>::TemplateTemplateClass(const int&)':
TemplateTemplateClass.cpp:8:11: error: class 'TemplateTemplateClass<T, T2, TemplateClass>' does not have any field named '_internalClass'
TemplateTemplateClass.cpp: In member function 'void TemplateTemplateClass<T, T2, TemplateClass>::doTest()':
TemplateTemplateClass.cpp:12:9: error: '_internalClass' was not declared in this scope
```

And if I change it like below then it can be compiled successfully.

```
class TemplateTemplateClass {
public:
    TemplateTemplateClass(const TemplateClass<T>& tempClass)
        : _internalClass(tempClass) {
    }

    void doTest() {
        _internalClass.doTest();
    }
private:
    TemplateClass<T> _internalClass;
};
```

So considering above error message, my question is that in `TemplateClass<T>`, what does `<T>` mean? Why it cannot be removed?

Comment: Are you trying to do [CRTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern)?

Answer (score 1):

You've told the compiler that `TemplateClass` is a template taking a single type argument:

```
template<typename T, typename T2, template <typename T> class TemplateClass>
                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Now, in order to use `TemplateClass`, you have to tell the compiler what that argument is, e.g. `T`, `T2`, `int`, `std::string` etc.

Answer (score 1):

```
template <typename T> class TemplateClass
```

Says `TemplateClass` is a template class. Templates are incomplete classes until you provide required types. In this case you should provide `T`.